# How to easily limit access to remote workspaces without terraform cloud?

Tags: terraform, terraform-workspace

I haven't found an easy way to separate my remote terraform workspaces, using a remote backend, where I can control access to different workspaces easily.

i.e. lets say I have 3 workspaces:

1. app-dev
2. app-int
3. app-prod

Let's say I wanted `app-dev` to have general access by the team, but not to other teams, and then I wanted `app-int` and especially `app-prod` to have limited access, where perhaps only CI can touch those workspaces.

**How can I do this, when not using terraform cloud?** This seems like obvious functionality to want, but it feels like they purposely left it out so teams have to buy terraform cloud to have any sense of security. I'm curious how other people have worked around it.

Comment: Are you using remote backend?

Comment: @Marcin yes - I am using a remote backend. I'll edit and try to make that clearer.